# What is faster and more efficient - begininvoke or synchronisecontext.post?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, multithreading

Did anyone tried to find out - what is faster and what is more efficient (less objects created and thus less GC is involved) - control.BeginInvoke or SynchroniseContext.Post ?

WPF, C#, .NET 4

I'd appreciate responses with practical backing rather than "I think" or "I heard somewhere"..

Cheers

*P.S. I am going to post a number of messages to few controls and I want it to be max efficient and fast (**few hundred updates / sec**). I know .NET can handle this (I did it before) but now I want it to be **as fast as possible**...*

Comment: As far as I can see WPF accepts for the Dispatcher.Begin/Invoke methods only Delegate as parameters. Delegate.Invoke is then needed to call it on the message loop which boils down to a reflection call which is much slower compared to a direct delegate invocation. Windows Forms has a special delegate type called MethodInvoker which get specially treated in the message loop to prevent this overhead. But since you are using WPF aaand want to be fast ... good luck.

Comment: if you are right then it is bad news indeed...

Comment: Why not batch the updates instead? Que all updating delegates and do a BeginInvoke a couple of times per second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BeginInvoke is 42.8% faster than SynchronizationContext.Post on my i7 desktop.

The results are:

```
Post      Send      Diff ms   Ratio
1280866   925416    35.00     -38.4%
1192232   916251    27.00     -30.1%
1338990   876215    46.00     -52.8%
1394783   863241    53.00     -61.6%
1332485   1046789   28.00     -27.3%
1335241   895784    43.00     -49.1%
1267470   1064894   20.00     -19.0%
1308461   884136    42.00     -48.0%
1321243   850704    47.00     -55.3%
1313230   896469    41.00     -46.5%
```

The code :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.RealTime;
    }

    Thread th;
    DispatcherSynchronizationContext ctx;
    protected override void OnContentRendered(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnContentRendered(e);

        Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;

        ctx = new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(this.Dispatcher);
        th = new Thread(Start);
        th.Start();
    }

    int MACRO = 10;
    int TESTS = 10;
    int LOOPS = 50000;
    void Start()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;

        // flush just in case
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            ctx.Post(Callback, 9999999);
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                new Action<object>((object state) => { txt2.Text = state.ToString(); }), 
                    DispatcherPriority.Send, 9999999);                
        }

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        // results
        List<Tuple<long, long>> results = new List<Tuple<long, long>>();

        // actual test
        for (int x = 0; x < MACRO; x++)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

            // sync context post
            long tick1, tick2;
            for (int i = 0; i < TESTS; i++)
            {
                sw.Start();
                for (int j = i; j < LOOPS + i; j++)
                {
                    ctx.Post(Callback, j);
                }
                sw.Stop();

                Thread.Sleep(1500);
            }

            tick1 = sw.ElapsedTicks;

            // begin invoke
            sw.Reset();
            for (int i = 0; i < TESTS; i++)
            {
                sw.Start();
                for (int j = i; j < LOOPS + i; j++)
                {
                    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                        new Action<object>((object state) => { txt2.Text = state.ToString(); }), 
                            DispatcherPriority.Normal, j);
                }
                sw.Stop();

                Thread.Sleep(1500);
            }

            tick2 = sw.ElapsedTicks;

            // store results
            results.Add(new Tuple<long, long>(tick1, tick2));

            // display to make it less boring
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { txt3.Text += string.Format("{0} {1}. ", tick1, tick2); }));
            Thread.Sleep(100);                
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var res in results)
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2:0.00}\t{3:0.0%}", 
                res.Item1, res.Item2, (res.Item1 - res.Item2) / 10000, res.Item2 != 0 ? 1.0 - res.Item1 / (double)res.Item2 : 0.0));

        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            new Action(() => { txb1.Text = sb.ToString(); }));                

    }

    void Callback(object state)
    {
        txt1.Text = state.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, there is no `Control.BeginInvoke` in WPF (that's winforms you're thinking of). Secondly, `SynchronizationContext` is an abstraction over whatever synchronization mechanism the current platform provides. In the case of WPF, it's an abstraction over the `Dispatcher`. Theoretically you pay a small price for using the abstraction rather than directly using the `Dispatcher`. But the abstraction is there for a good reason - sometimes you need to write thread synchronization code that is independent of the platform. If you don't then by all means use the `Dispatcher` directly.

Comment: Putting aside my typ0 control/dispatcher.... What I really need to know - does BeginInvoke more work and / or create more internal objects thant Post... I assume Post does what the old windows message pump does - simply put a little object in the queue... Is my assumption correct and if yes - how much more work BeginInvoke does? thank you

Comment: It seems BeginInvoke slightly faster than Post. On 50000 messages looped without delay I got performance on my slow laptop about 15 msg/ms.

Comment: By the way 15 msgs/ms is not the perf you do get. You did basically measure how fast your messages can be put into a queue. This is not the perf how fast you can update your UI. The real message loop perf is more like 100-1000 msgs/s depending on how much drawing you do in your actual call.

Comment: no. the messages can be put faster than that. i tinkered with the delay after the loop to find out approximate delay between end of the loop and the last render on the screen. for 50K sampling set the error is tolerable. so i factored that delay (between last message posted and the last message shown on the screen) and got 15 msg/ms

Comment: * correction: I can get 35 msg/ms rendered in WPF textBlock on i7 PC.